# Two If statements execute at once, instead of one

Tags: c, user-interface, if-statement, int, case

I've got a program that takes input from a char Array, using the strtok function to check if the input contains the words "up" or "down". If it contains the word "up", my b value is set false (i.e b = 0) and my c value is set to false as well. If the char array contains the words "down", b is set to false, however my c value is set to true (i.e c= 1).

My problem occurs when the word "up" are contained in the string, as  the first if statement executes, and prints the resultant characters on the screen, but somehow the second if also executes printing those characters as well. Any input on this matter would be much appreciated

EDIT: The same problem occurs if I use the word "down", both if statements are executed.

```
int moveC(int y, int x, int b, int i, int c) {
    // int c is a static variable(static int c = FALSE;) defined in the previous function
    int j;
    int k;

switch (b) //assume b is always false (which it is)
{
    case FALSE:
        if (c == 0) {
            mvprintw(y, x, "^");
            refresh();

            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                mvprintw(y + j, x, ".");
                refresh();
            }
            break;
        }

        if (c == 1) //tried using else if, same result
        {

            mvprintw(y, x, "^");
            refresh();

            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                mvprintw(y - j, x, ".");
                refresh();
            }
            break;
        }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a step-through debugger? What did you observe?

Comment: Not exactly sure if that is at all possible (as I'm coding on my raspberry PI). Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not that familiar with the so called "step-through debugger".

Comment: @user20842454566 try learning to use gdb, your life as a C programmer will be so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is most likely executing twice. The giveaway is that you tried an if/else. Only one block will *ever* be executed in one execution of an if statement.

Comment: Based on your response, I still don't understand how to fix my current problem, care to expand at all?

Comment: In an if/else statement the code compiles (gets translated into a language the computer can better understand) into code wherein it is _impossible_ (for the sake of our argument) to execute more than one section of that statement. I don't know what your program does, but its probably a timing condition your seeing, where your code is executing faster than you anticipate and has already gone through that section of code multiple times before you see that output. Maybe putting a pause after that statement so you can see the output would help.

Comment: Assuming you can see the output, add a print statement at the top of the function outside any conditional code and you can see how many times it is being called as well as any output that happens in each call.

Comment: If I'm understanding your comment correctly, i've added a mvprintw statement at the beginning of the moveC Function. The statement is only printed once, so I'm assuming it is only being called once?

Comment: How can it only be printing once if your other characters are printing multiple times? Again, not sure of the specifics but make sure you change what prints each time you print your test line in moveC. Use a global int and just increment before printing it.